# Dealing with followup questions posted as answers by new users

Tags: discussion, review

When I am reviewing, especially in the first time post reviews, and I flag a not-an-answer answer, I try to leave the poster some feedback in the hope he/she reads it before it gets deleted (sometimes that is wishful thinking).

When the poster is basically asking "me too, what do you end up doing?"  How should we try to guide them to the appropriate course of action? For a more experienced user, the appropriate action would be to post the follow-up as a comment or even better add a bounty to the question.

But what is the appropriate action for a new user, especially if the original question did not have a real answer?  Should we recommend he reask the same question in hopes of finding an answer?  Is there another alternative that we can recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One choice (which I would choose over asking a duplicate question) would be to prompt the new user to make an edit to the existing question to make it better... that would pop it back to the front of the line and maybe get some new people to look at it, and it would get them into helping improve the site.